# System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly. Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, badimageformatexception

So I'm making a Microsoft Flight Simulator plugin that gets some data from the sim and makes something with it, doesn't really matter as i'm not there yet...

Im using SimConnect to connect with the simulator, a first-party SDK from Microsoft, but I cant fully understand the docs.

I've looked online and its pretty much always top change the architecture to x86, so I've done that (I think) [Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNctX.png) but it didn't solve it.

Here are the docs: https://docs.flightsimulator.com/html/Programming_Tools/SimConnect/SimConnect_SDK.htm

and the code:

```cs
using Microsoft.FlightSimulator.SimConnect;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


internal class Program
{
    SimConnect? simConnect;
    private readonly IntPtr handle = new IntPtr(0);

    void Run()
    {
        const int WM_USER_SIMCONNECT = 0x0402;
        try
        {
            simConnect = new SimConnect("Managed Data Request", handle, WM_USER_SIMCONNECT, null, 0);
            // You can perform other operations with simConnect here.
        }
        catch (COMException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        if (simConnect != null)
        {
            simConnect.Dispose();
            simConnect = null;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create an instance of the Program class
        Program program = new Program();

        // Call the Run method to execute its code
        program.Run();
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

I've looked at the docs, but it wasn't useful/could understand the useful part
I've looked online and its pretty much always top change the architecture to x86, so I've done that (I think) [Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNctX.png) but it didn't solve it.

Comment: According to [Microsoft Flight Simulator Software Development Kit! This SDK](https://docs.flightsimulator.com/html/Programming_Tools/SimConnect/Programming_SimConnect_Clients_using_Managed_Code.htm): _Ensure that .NET Framework Version 4.7 is installed and then...The managed SimConnect assembly is installed in the GAC (global assembly cache) during the installation of the SimConnect SDK.._

Comment: Are you using _.NET_ or _.NET Framework_? According to [Global assembly cache APIs are obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/global-assembly-cache-apis-obsolete): _.NET Core and .NET 5 and later versions eliminate the concept of the global assembly cache (GAC) that was present in .NET Framework. As such, all .NET Core and .NET 5+ APIs that deal with the GAC either fail or perform no operation_.

Comment: How can I see which one I’m using?

Comment: One way is to look in the _.csproj_ file. Another way is to look at the project properties in Visual Studio. However, since your code is rather minimal, just create a new project and ensure that you select the template that says _.NET Framework_.